# Which andrioid version should I use to practice in Android Studio?

Tags: android

HI I have just started to learn android on Android Studio. I have seen several tutorial video. So, I was wandering what version of Device should I prefer to use for better practice. In the tutorials nexus version was used.

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend using the version you have (do you have a device?), or using the latest stable version, or if you are following specific instruction materials then use the version they based their materials on for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Nexus VMs. You could also connect your phone (if it is an Android device) and use it to test your app.